# По аналогии с vector<int> vec_1(50) не могу понять, как задать размер для vector<vector<int>> vec_2

Tags: c++

Не смог придумать, как сделать вот что.

понятно, что `vector<int> vec_1(50)` - это вектор из 50 элементов.

А если я теперь хочу сделать вектор из 10 векторов, в каждом из которых по 50 элементов - как это синтаксически оформить?

Простые попытки написать что то типа

```
    vector<vector<int>> vec_2(10,50);
```

или

```
    vector<vector<int>> vec_2(10)(50);
```

-не прокатывают...

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B)) пример двумерного массива

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов - спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Прошу прощения за беспокойство и простой вопрос.

Мне ответ подсказал Юрий Козлов, и ответ этот звучит так:

```
    vector<vector<int>> vec_2(10, vector<int>(50));
```

(написано в предположении, что std:: писать не обязательно)

Ну, в общем, не самое тривиальное задание размера :-)